# Как быстро произойдет ошибка в коде?

Tags: память, указатели, c++, функции

Здравствуйте!

Интересует такая вещь, как быстро слетит такая программа:

```
class S{
   ...
   char *s;
   ...

   void sss(){
       ...
       s="Hellow W";
       ...
   }
};
```

На сколько я понимаю, как только произойдет выход по ret ***, строка s может содержать всё что угодно. Это в лучшем. В худшем случае, может успеть в фрейме, отведенном под функцию, затереться... Но в любом случае, если предположить, что продолжительное время код будет интенсивно работать, это приведет к ошибке. Верно мыслю?)

**Обновление**

Не влезло в коментарий:

А, извините, в дальнейшем я использую s в других методах класса S, я читаю по s строку. Как же не правильное понимание указателей?! s занимает в памяти 1 байт, и эта память, которая отводится на s предназначена для того, чтобы хранить адрес памяти куда указывает s. Так как s занимает 1 байт, то я могу найти только символ H. Но, зная, что строка заканчивается '\0' можно с уверенность идти дальше от символа 'H' до символа '\0', зная, что будет считано "Hellow W\0".  Теперь, суть вопроса, кто дает гарантию, что после выхода из функции sss(), в памяти по адресу, хранимому в s не будет содержаться нечто подобного: "3243rwrryr564tet46t4tet ......  \0".

s правильно укажет на адрес, а содержимое расположенное по адресу содержит не только не 'Н', но и всякую ерунду. Откуда такая уверенность? Строка введенная от руки является static???

Comment: Я уже стал сомневаться что это приведет к ошибке. Это сложный вопрос?

Comment: s/байта/бита/

Comment: По сути вопроса. Память под массив распределена статически и освобождена не будет до завершения программы. Указатель s содержит адрес первого символа этой строки и позволяет обращаться к ней. Никаких проблем нет, но вы можете получить исключение при попытке модифицировать этот массив, например * s=0; что-то типа "нельзя изменять данные в этой локации", и то это в зависимости от системы и транслятора, т.е. и такое может прокатить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кроме мест, где у Вас многоточия, тут ломаться просто нечему, если компилятор позволяет записать адрес на константную строку в переменную.

**Обновление**

У Вас неправильное понимание работы с указателями. `s` - простая переменная. Вы в эту переменную записываете адрес строки. В данном случае даже не важно, куда указывает этот адрес, т.к. **Вы не используете `s`**.

**Обновление**

> s занимает в памяти 1 байт, и эта память, которая отводится на s предназначена для того, чтобы хранить адрес памяти куда указывает s

`s` занимает в памяти `32/64 бита` (`4/8 байт`) (в зависимости от разрядности системы) и хранит **адрес** строки. Все, что у Вас идет далее, по тексту - ошибочные следствия из ошибочного утверждения.
 --
p.s.: когда текст не влезает в комментарий, но надо именно комментарий, отвечайте **ответом**, после чего, преобразуйте ответ обратно в **комментарий**, так все поместится.

**Обновление**

> [[@mega](/users/8766/mega)](/users/8766/mega) может все-таки 4/8 байт? (32/64 бита)

ага, очепятался, конечно: 32/64 **бита**
 --
пока печатал, думал про разрядность системы )) [исправил]

Comment: Но память-то не выделена через new. Как это выглядит в памяти? Я это вижу так: мы в память(функции) вбили символы, неясно в какое место памяти. Указателю показали куда смотреть. Есть гарантия, что после выхода из функции строка останется в памяти, что ее не перетрет что-либо?

Comment: @mega может все-таки 4/8 байт? (32/64 бита)